# Pair items in a list by their type and display in the view in one loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5

```
Model.Results
```

is a list object that holds list of result model.

```
public List<result> Results {get; set;}

class result
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int resultId {get; set;}
   public string resultName {get; set;}
   public int resultTypeId {get; set;}
   public string resultValue {get; set;}
}
```

What I need to do now is display that list in the view which is straight forward:

```
@foreach(var result in Model.Results)
{
    <ul>
    <li> @result.resultName</li>
    <li> @result.resultValue</li>
    </ul>
}
```

But what I need to do is check if the resultTypeId is the same I want to display the resultValue on the same row:

```
 @foreach(var result in Model.Results)
 {
     <ul>
     <li> @result.resultName</li>
     @if(result.resultTypeId == any other result.resultTypeId in the list)
     {
        <li> @result.resultValue - @the other result.resultValue</li>
      }
     @else
    {
        <li> @result.resultValue</li>
    }
   </ul>
 }
```

Please let me know if you need me to illustrate more. When I look at the logic it looks straight forward but when I start coding I can't see a way round it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `-` a subtraction or a separator charcter?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. It's a separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your items by the ID:

```
 @foreach(var resultGroup in Model.Results.GroupBy(result => result.resultTypeId))
 {
     <ul>
     <li> @resultGroup.First().resultName</li>
     @foreach (var result in resultGroup) {
        <li> @result.resultValue</li>
     }
     </ul>
 }
```

Comment: I love this answer! Simple and neat with no need to create extra objects! Thanks alot @Sefe!

Answer (score 1):

In your model create a property that returns all the `resultTypeId` as a list:

```
public IEnumerable<int> ResultsTypeIds
{
    get
    {
        return Results.DistinctBy(x=>x.resultTypeId).Select(x=>x.resultTypeId);    
    }
}
```

In your View you can then itterate over that collection

```
@foreach(var resultTypeId in Model.ResultsTypeIds)
{
    <ul>
    @foreach(var result in Model.Results)
    {
        <li>@result.resultValue</li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to format your data in the way view expects it to be, like:

```
Model.Results.GroupBy(r=>r.resultTypeId)
     .Select(gr=>new {resultTypeId = gr.Key, resultName = gr.First().resultName,  Items = gr.ToList()})
     .ToList();
```

Than on the view simply iterate over groups and items in each group:

```
@foreach(var group in Model.GroupedResults)
 {
     <ul>
     <li> @group.resultName</li>
     <li>
     @foreach(var item in group.Items)
     {
       @item.resultValue <br/>
     }
     </li>
   </ul>
 }
```

You might want something else as view markup, but it should give you the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much. I like the suggestion of formatting the data the way view expects it. Deserved to be the accepted answer because of the good practice!